# Problem with side scroller href with CSS and html

Tags: html, css

I've been practicing code trying to make website with HTML and CSS, and I had an idea for a menu that you can scroll sideways. You've probably seen them, I have everything down but the `href` tags. Once you click on the letters, its supposed to jump to a certain "menuItem". click a, you go to b, b to c, c back to a. The problem is that it only works once, and after that, it stops jumping. So I can press a, it'll go to b, and then stop working when I press b to go to c. Please help, thanks.

```css
.portfolioWrapper .portScroller {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
}

.portfolioWrapper .portScroller li.a {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.portfolioWrapper .portScroller li.b {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.portfolioWrapper .portScroller li.c {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

li.a a.oneAnch {
  text-align: right;
}

li.a a.twoAnch {
  text-align: right;
}

li.a a.threeAnch {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolioWrapper">
  <a id="portAnchor"></a>
  <div class="portScroller">
    <li class="a"><a href="#prj2" class="one">a</a></li>
    <a id="prj1" class="oneAnch"></a>
    <li class="b"><a href="#prj3" class="two">b</a></li>
    <a id="prj2" class="twoAnch"></a>
    <li class="c"><a href="#prj1" class="three">c</a></li>
    <a id="prj3" class="threeAnch"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I press the numbers in the snippet above .. A goes to B .. B goes to C ..  Seems to work as expected?

Comment: When he  press c last, it goes to b instead of going to a.

Comment: @Zak It works on the Stack Overflow IDE, but not with the entirety of my code. In order to make it work, you have to scroll up a bit and then press the tag, otherwise, it doesn't work. Check out  https://hetyug04.github.io/hetyug04/newPortfolio/index.html

Comment: @SercanSebetçi Even after I impleted your code, the problem remains the same. Its only an issue in my actual website implementation. You have to scroll up a bit in order to for the tab to change. Check out https://hetyug04.github.io/hetyug04/newPortfolio/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You avoid this problem by defining an `<a>` element to show the starting position before the list.

```css
/* The following styles have been added. */
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.portfolioWrapper .portScroller {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
}

.portfolioWrapper .portScroller li.a {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.portfolioWrapper .portScroller li.b {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.portfolioWrapper .portScroller li.c {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

li.a a.oneAnch {
  text-align: right;
}

li.a a.twoAnch {
  text-align: right;
}

li.a a.threeAnch {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolioWrapper">
    <a id="portAnchor"></a>

    <div class="portScroller"> 
        <!-- The following line has been added. -->
        <a id="start" class="oneAnch"></a>

        <li class="a">
            <a href="#prj2" class="one">First</a>
        </li>
        <a id="prj1" class="oneAnch"></a>

        <li class="b">
            <a href="#prj3" class="two">Second</a>
        </li>
        <a id="prj2" class="twoAnch"></a>

        <li class="c">
            <!-- The line below has been updated. -->
            <a href="#start" class="three">Thirth</a>
        </li>
        <a id="prj3" class="threeAnch"></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think we didn't agree on the right keywords; you need a floating <div> element with buttons horizontally. If you need something like this, see these examples: [jQuery Horizontal Scroll Using Buttons](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZdCw7IEYdV5YVeGg33oX?p=preview&preview), [Make A Button To Scroll Horizontally in div](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56392370/15032688), [Arrow Buttons for Responsive Horizontal Scroll Menu](https://codepen.io/mahish/pen/RajmQw), [Horizontal Scrolling Item in Center Position](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/qNErz)